# tags not rendering the right url

Tags: channel-entries, tags

i can't seem to find out why a tag would be rendering the wrong url.

the problem is that `{webm}` should be rendering to `http://www.hallmarklighting.com/video/hallmarkYT.webm` with the `/video/` 
not as 
`http://www.hallmarklighting.com/hallmarkYT.webm` which it's currently doing.

the channel field is set to *file* and the directory is set to grab the video from the folder *video*

let me know if there is anymore relevant info needed.

**EE markup:**

```
                <div class="lb-content"><!-- main content of lightbox -->
                    <video width="640" height="480" poster="{poster}" preload="metadata" controls>
                            <source src="{mov}" type="video/mov" />
                            <source src="{mp4}" type="video/mp4" />
                            <source src="{webm}" type="video/webm" />
                            You're browser seems to be out of date as it doesn't support Video, visit <a href="{alternative_link}" target="_blank">youtube.com/{title}</a> to watch this video.
                    </video>                                
                </div><!-- end content -->
```

**what's being rendered:**

```
<div class="lb-content"><!-- main content of lightbox -->
    <video width="640" height="480" poster="http://www.hallmarkcollective.com/images/uploads/hallmarkIntro.jpg" preload="metadata" controls>
        <source src="http://www.hallmarklighting.com/hallmarkYT.mov" type="video/mov" />
        <source src="http://www.hallmarklighting.com/hallmarkYT.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="http://www.hallmarklighting.com/hallmarkYT.webm" type="video/webm" />
        You're browser seems to be out of date as it doesn't support Video, visit <a href="http://youtu.be/E6S9vadARk0" target="_blank">youtube.com/Introducing Hallmark Lighting</a> to watch this video.
    </video>                                
</div><!-- end content -->
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [URL of the upload directory](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#url-of-upload-directory) is set wrong.